# Valgrind, it is possible to get the number of line?

Tags: c, valgrind

i have project in C language, but if i start check valgrind, i have error

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
at 0x804B2C3: nameOfMethodC (in ...ap.exe)
by 0x804A62E: nameOfMethodB (in ...ap.exe)
by 0x80493A2: nameOfMethodA (in ...ap.exe)
```

How can i find this uninitialized variable?

Is it possible to get line numbers? For example:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
at  at 0x804B2C3: nameOfMethodC (in ...file.c on 123 line)
. . . .
```

For start valgrind i use:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./ap.exe param1 param2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `ap.exe` is compiled with debugging information enabled and optimizations disabled.

Comment: how i can check this?

Comment: If you are compiling with gcc/clang, make sure the `-g` flag is there. You may also want to add `-O0` to disable all optimizations (not really required, but will make errors clear).

Comment: Depends on your compiler/IDE. For GCC, you need to add the `-g` and `-O0` options. IDEs often have some sort of checkbox somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes ./out
```

Above `valgrind` command will give using `uninitialized` variable

Comment: valgrind: Bad option '--track-origins=yes'; aborting.

Comment: It was [added in valgrind 3.4.0](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.undeferrors).